# Creating and deleting files on database insert with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating objects/database entries for my flask application with flask-sqlalchemy. Each entry has corresponding files and directories, which I currently create in a different method before creating the database entry, and I remove them manually after deleting the database entry, similar to this:

```
init_files(name, some, parameters)
thing_to_insert = SomeModel(name, some, parameters)
db.session.add(thing_to_insert)
db.session.commit()
```

Now I want to do this in a more organized fashion, so I stumbled upon sqlalchemy events, e.g. 'before_insert' and 'after_delete'. Is this the correct (and ideal) way to deal with such requirements? Is there a way to cancel the insertion if the creation of files fails or remove the files again if there is a DB rollback?

Comment: Why don't you use classmethods?

Comment: Such as __init__()? I would like the code to be automatically executed on insert/delete so that my main code looks cleaner and I don't have to call an additional method every time I insert an object.